# Splitting a BigTiff using tifffile

Tags: python, memory, tiff, clip

I am having trouble splitting a BigTiff. I am orginally using @Ivan code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953373/how-to-split-image-into-multiple-pieces-in-python). I had to modify it a bit since I am using a .tif that was larger than 4GB. Pillow [does not support](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4513) BigTiffs. So I ended up using `tifffile`. The code is running, though the image is not being clipped to the `box` parameter. I am thinking it has to do that `tifffile` reads the image in as a `numpy array` and is not actually being clipped by anything???

I've also noticed that when this code is running my memory is just about maxing out. I tried assigning the data type to a unassigned 8-bit and that drastically helped. Should I compress it as well? I don't want to change the data too much since I will be classifying them and do not want to lose/change data.

```
import os
from itertools import product
import tifffile

def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out, d):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = tifffile.imread(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))
    print(type(img))
    w = img.shape[0]
    h = img.shape[1]


    grid = list(product(range(0, h - h % d, d), range(0, w - w % d, d)))
    for i, j in grid:
        box = (j, i, j + d, i + d)
        out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{j}{ext}')
        img = img.clip(box)
        img = img.astype('uint8')
        tifffile.imsave(out, img)


tile('Orthomosaic_export_MonFeb01193821460106.tif',
     r'D:\ortho',
     r'D:\model_images',
     1000)
```

Comment: [`img.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) clips the values in the array. It doesn't change the shape. Use [slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) instead.

Comment: @cgohlke so `img=img[box]`?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up merging this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685274/divide-an-image-into-5x5-blocks-in-python-and-compute-histogram-for-each-block) into my code and finally got it to run.

```
import os
import tifffile

def tile(filename, dir_in, dir_out):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    img = tifffile.imread(os.path.join(dir_in, filename))

    windowsize_r = 10000
    windowsize_c = 10000

    i = 0
    for r in range(0, img.shape[0] - windowsize_r, windowsize_r):
        for c in range(0, img.shape[1] - windowsize_c, windowsize_c):
            window = img[r:r + windowsize_r, c:c + windowsize_c]
            out = os.path.join(dir_out, f'{name}_{i}_{ext}')
            tifffile.imsave(out, window)
            i = i + 1

tile('Shopfield_Orthomosaic_export_MonFeb01193821460106.tif',
     r'D:\ortho',
     r'D:\model_images')
```